# Public private variable connection issue in 2 Java Classes

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, private, public

I have two files, `Display.java` (first) and then `Lancher.java` (second). They are both under the same project but are two different classes. I want to have a display image, but the width and height from the Launcher file come up as errored. I don't know why, as both width and height are `public` in the `Display` file.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Display extends JFrame {
    
    private Canvas canvas;
    
    public Display(int width, int height) {
        setTitle("Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Process will still be running but application closes when cross is pressed
        setResizable(false);
        
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        //Set size to pass in with dimension
        canvas.setFocusable((false));
        add(canvas);
        pack();
        //Add canvas to display & calculate size of display frame
        
        setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        //To open frame in the center of screen as opposed to side
        setVisible(true);
        
        
    }

}
```

Launcher.java

```
public class Launcher {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display( width: 800, height: 600);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not valid Java syntax... Try `new Display(800, 600);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of the `Display` object in your `Launcher` class isn't valid syntax. This would be the proper way to initialize it:

```
Display display = new Display(800, 600);
```

Notice the parameter names/identifiers are not used when passing values into the construction of the object.

Answer (score 1):

`width` and `height` are parameter names. Java doesn't have named arguments, only positional arguments. In other words, drop the labels in the call to the constructor, and you should be OK:

```java
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display(800, 600);
    }
}
```